# Error envío datagramas UDP Cliente (Android) y Servidor (Eclipse)

Tags: java, android, servidor

Buenas estoy haciendo una aplicación que envia los datos recogidos por un smartphone a una base de datos para trabajar con ellos posteriormente, los códigos son los siguientes:
CLIENTE

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  implements SensorEventListener, View.OnClickListener{

private SensorManager mSensorManager;
private Sensor mAccelerometer;
private Sensor mBrujula;
private Button iniciar_crono;

//
private InetAddress IPAddress=InetAddress.getByName("xxx.xxx.xxx");
public  float azimut;
private int puertoServ=5000;

    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if(event.sensor.getType() == mAccelerometer.getType()){
        float x = event.values[0];
        float y = event.values[1];
        float z = event.values[2];
        enviarDatosAcelerometro(x, y, z, azimut);
    }
    else if(event.sensor.getType() == mBrujula.getType()){
        this.azimut = event.values[0];
    }
}

public void enviarDatosAcelerometro(float x, float y, float z, float azimut2){
    String info = "x="+x+" y="+y+" z="+z+" grados="+azimut2;
    new EnviarDatos(info).execute();
}

    private class EnviarDatos extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    private String info;
    public EnviarDatos(String info){
        this.info = info;
    }
    protected Void doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        try {
            byte[] bytesInfo = info.getBytes();
            DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(bytesInfo, bytesInfo.length, IPAddress, puertoServ);
            clientSocket.send(sendPacket);
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    }
}
```

SERVIDOR

```
public class Servidor {
private final static int puerto = 5000;

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{

    try {
    DatagramSocket socketUDP = new DatagramSocket(5000);    
    System.out.println("Servidor> Servidor iniciado");    
    System.out.println("Servidor> En espera de cliente..."); 

    Socket clientSocket;
    byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];

    //Para pasar el byte de String a double
    double x, y, z, grados;
    String xS, yS, zS, gradosS;
    boolean continuar=true;


    while(true) {
            // Construimos el DatagramPacket para recibir peticiones
            DatagramPacket datosCliente = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);

            // Leemos una petición del DatagramSocket
            socketUDP.receive(datosCliente);

            System.out.print("Datagrama recibido del host: " + datosCliente.getAddress());
            System.out.println(" desde el puerto remoto: " +datosCliente.getPort());

            String sentence = new String( datosCliente.getData(), 0, datosCliente.getLength()-1);

        if(sentence.startsWith("termina")){
            continuar = false;
            }

        else{
            String[] a = sentence.split(" ");
            xS = a[0].substring(a[0].indexOf("=")+1, a[0].length());
            yS = a[1].substring(a[1].indexOf("=")+1, a[1].length());
            zS = a[2].substring(a[2].indexOf("=")+1, a[2].length());
            gradosS = a[3].substring(a[3].indexOf("=")+1, a[3].length());
            x = Double.parseDouble(xS);
            y = Double.parseDouble(yS);
            z = Double.parseDouble(zS);
            grados = Double.parseDouble(gradosS);

            }
    }
        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }

}
}
```

Me salta el sigiente error cuando ejecuto la clase Servidor

```
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: Cannot bind
at java.net.DualStackPlainDatagramSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainDatagramSocketImpl.bind0(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
at java.net.DatagramSocket.bind(Unknown Source)
at java.net.DatagramSocket.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.net.DatagramSocket.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.net.DatagramSocket.<init>(Unknown Source)
at paquete.Servidor.main(Servidor.java:19)
```

¿Alguien podría explicarme el motivo del error por favor? Saludos

Answer (score 1):

La primera opción es reiniciar para liberar el puerto si es que este esta siendo usado por otra aplicación.

Si el problema continua, te sugiero revisar mediante el Monitor de Recursos (resmon.exe) que aplicaciones están usando el puerto 5000:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> - Puedes identificar el proceso que usa el mismo puerto, incluso puedes cambiar de puerto en tu aplicación por uno que no sea usado.
> - Es posible también que estés creando más de una instancia del servidor.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la información, me ha servido de gran ayuda ;)